# A number from Multiple Numbers

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have an assignment. It was suppose to do the following:
--> Take an integer input(say 100)
--> Add the digits till the sum is a single digit number(1)

My program till now is:

```
goodvalue1=False
goodvalue2=False

while (goodvalue1==False):
    try:
        num=input("Please enter a number: ")
    except ValueError:
        print ("Wrong input. Try again.")
    else:
        goodvalue1=True


if (goodvalue1==True):
    ListOfDigits=list(map(int,str(num)))
    sum=10
    while(sum>9):
        Sum=sum(ListOfDigits)
        if (Sum>9):
            ListOfDigits=list(map(int,str(Sum)))
            Sum=sum(ListOfDigits)
```

Comment: Well, what's the issue?

Comment: Some thoughts: you don't need to check `if (something == True)`, just do `if something`. For your while loop, you can do `while not goodvalue1`. Also, you don't need the parentheses in your if and while conditions. Don't use variables that shadow built-in functions (ie `sum`). Don't have your variables capitalized to start - good style has vars start lowercase and classes start uppercase. I highly recommend taking a look at the [Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#introduction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those booleans are not needed. You can factor the code down to:

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Please enter a number: ")) # Note how I've added int()
        break # Breaks out of the loop. No need for a boolean.
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong input. Try again.")
```

I don't see why you called `list(map(int, str(num)))`; but I *think* you were intending to put `int()` around your input. So I added one in above. Now it can catch an error :).

Now, to get one digit, you can use another `while` loop here:

```
while num > 9:
    num = sum(map(int, str(num)))
```

Pretty much this creates `[1, 0, 0]` which `sum()` then calls on. This repeats until it is no longer a two digit number (or three, four, etc)

So altogether:

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Please enter a number: ")) # Note how I've added int()
        break # Breaks out of the loop. No need for a boolean.
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong input. Try again.")

while num > 9: # While it is a two digit number
    num = sum(map(int, str(num)))
```

---

Just note that for conditional statements, it's never pythonic to do `a == True` or `b == False`.

From the [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id37):

> Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==.
>
> Yes:   if greeting:
>
> No:    if greeting == True:
>
> Worse: if greeting is True:

Comment: That doesn't answer the question for input: "12399"

Comment: @dav1d With the quotation marks? Well it shouldn't...

Comment: I think dav1d is right though (quotation marks aside).

Comment: No without the quotation marks, 12399 = 24, 24 has more than one digit. See my answer.

Comment: Why the `len(str(num)) != 1` this is a useless call to `str` and `len` and not very "pythonic" (mentioning this because of your link to PEP8). Simply check if `num > 9`.

Comment: @dav1d Since when was it not very pythonic? I don't think it's useless at all

Comment: @Haidro it's to useless calls with no benefit. `num > 9` is obvious, your `len(str(num)) != 1` isn't on the first glance. "Why does he convert a number to a string then measuer the length?" instead of "Oh number is greater than 9, do it again!"

Comment: @dav1d Hmm, you have a point there. You could argue that mine's more readable, but you are correct.

Comment: You still have the old code in there a bit above.

Comment: @dav1d you didn't see that ;)

Comment: Hello! if greeting shows a wrong input on my python 3.3.2 hence, I did not use it...

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. Here's what you need to change:

```
Sum=sum(ListOfDigits)
while(Sum>9):
    Sum=sum(ListOfDigits)
    if (Sum>9):
        ListOfDigits=list(map(int,str(Sum)))
        Sum=sum(ListOfDigits)
```

In this code, you have  a while loop that executes when `sum` is bigger than 9. So why use another variable `Sum` (also, it makes for really difficult-to-read code)? Do this instead:

```
while(sum>9):
    sum=sum(ListOfDigits)
    ListOfDigits=list(map(int,str(sum)))
```

This is only to show you what went wrong with your code. I wouldn't recommend using it (look below for what I would do). First, you mix variable-naming conventions, which is a very bad idea, especially when you work in a team (even otherwise, can you imagine looking at your code a month or six months from now?).
Second, you don't ever use `goodvalue2`; what's it there for?
Third, if `goodvalue1` is only ever going to be a `bool`, then why check `if (goodvalue1==True)`? `if goodvalue1` is clearer and more pythonic.
Please, for the love of all that is good, use some spaces in your code. Eyes get very strained after looking at expressions like `ListOfDigits=list(map(int,str(num)))` for a while. Try `ListOfDigits = list(map(int, str(num)))` instead.

Personally, I would do this:

```
num = None
while num is None:
    try:
        num = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        num = None

num = sum(int(i) for i in str(num))
while num > 9:
    num = sum(int(i) for i in str(num)) # this uses a list comprehension. Look it up, they're very useful and powerful!
```

Comment: This code is horrible Python but still correct, why the downvote?

Comment: @dav1d: thank you. I was wondering the same thing

Comment: @dav1d: try running it, then come back and tell us how correct it is. It tries to call a builtin function that's been shadowed by a local variable, and suggests undoing the part of the code that kind of sort of attempted to stop shadowing it (granted, unsuccessfully) by changing capitalization.

Comment: @Wobble I take back what I said, I only saw the idea behind this non-python idomatic code. Of course this can't run.

Comment: @Wooble: fair point. I just fixed that. This is one of the reasons I hate capitalization based variable separation

Comment: @RussW: thanks for the bug report. Would it be too much to ask SO for code refactoring support?

Answer (score 1):

My take on this:

```
inp = None
while inp is None:
    try:
        inp = int(input('Enter number here: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid Input, try again')

summed = sum(map(int, str(inp)))
while summed > 9:
    summed = sum(map(int, str(summed)))

print('The result is {}'.format(summed))
```

For an explanation @Haidro did a good job: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17787707/969534

Answer (score -1):

RECURSION !

Calculate the sum of the digits. Check if the sum has one digit or multiple digit. If one digit, that is your answer, else, call the function on the sum again.

```
def oneDigitSum(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    else:
        return oneDigitSum(sum([int(i) for i in str(n)]))
        # [f(elem) for elem in li] = [f(a), f(b), .... ] where li = [a, b, ... ]
        # sum returns the total of the numbers in list

while True: # continue this loop for eternity, until it gets break
    try:
        num=int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        print(oneDigitSum(num))
        break # printed the sum, now I can break the loop peace fully
    except ValueError:
        print ("Wrong input. Try again.")
        continue # oops, looks like wrong input, lets continue the loop
```

Comment: If you're going to use list comprehensions to answer a user who seems to be new to Python, please explain what it is. They're not trivial to understand for new people.

Comment: I got downvoted before I added this code.

Comment: I noticed. I didn't downvote, I'm just commenting on how to expand the answer.